# can server timeout be controlled by code?

Tags: php, file-upload, timeout

I have used a tutorial to create a PHP script to upload files to a server. It works beautifully for images and small files < 10mb but over that size it fails. I believe that this may be due to a server timeout. The question is, if I am correct in my assumption is there a way to tell the server to wait until the file has uploaded?

Of course there may be another issue I haven't thought of, according to the script I have the large uploads aren't producing an error and the "success" text is displayed!

Any helpful advice would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thanks I'll look at the link

Comment: Hope it helps :) Otherwise, feel free to ask!

Comment: It turns out that my assumption was incorrect and I now belive that I have an issue with file-size

Comment: You can change that in php.ini - If you have access to that, that is.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the timeout using `set_time_limit($seconds)`

If you set `$seconds` to 0, the server won't time out - but use this very carefully!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll try this as well as read the link above.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP there's a function called [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/set_time_limit) which you can use to set how long it'll take before PHP terminates due to running to long. Be careful with it though because setting it to 0 can leave php processing waiting around forever and eat up your server resources.

You can also set this directive in php.ini or from apache .htaccess files.

There is also [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

make sure your allowed over 10mb for uploads
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

then with php

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

This [directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) can be useful:

- upload_max_filesize
- max_execution_time

This directives can be changed in php.ini or via function [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP as an Apache module and previous answers doesn't work, you can look at [Apache timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout) but it's not advisable.